# How can I set a default datetime value in eve?

Tags: python, eve

For example, for a key:

`'joinDate' : {'type' : 'datetime'}`

How can I make it automatically get posted with the current date without being explicitly given in POST method?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an [Insert Event](http://python-eve.org/features.html#insert-events), like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

"""some code omitted"""

def insert_join_date(items):
    for item in items:
        item["joinDate"] = datetime.utcnow()

app.on_insert_your_schema += insert_join_date
```

The previous example is based on `on_insert_<resource_name>(items)` and applies to a specific resource --**your_schema** in this case. If this logic should by applied to all the schemas, then `on_insert(resource_name, items)` can be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Python `datetime.datetime.now()` method like so:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 30, 14, 51, 25, 977000)
```